# How to get one database collection data in another database

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Our application needs 5 collections in a DB. When we add client to our application we would like to maintain separate DB for each customer. 
For example, if we have 10 customers, we would have 10 DBs and 50 collections (each DB has 5 collection). This way we can separate each customer data.

My question is: How to get one database collection data in another database (Main DB)?

Comment: Is the query in the shell or using a particular driver?

Comment: shell.thanks in advance

Comment: `db.getSiblingDB('test').foo.find()` where `test` is the other database, `foo` is the collection name to query and `find` is the command.